# ListDataModel<Car> or just ListDataModel?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to clone example here http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf
But Netbeans tell me that "type ListDataModel does not take parameters" at

```
public class CarDataModel extends ListDataModel<Car> implements SelectableDataModel<Car>
```

line at CarDataModel.java

If I remove Car parameter, like

```
public class CarDataModel extends ListDataModel implements SelectableDataModel<Car>
```

it compiles without any error and jsf page open with empty datatable.

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for helping.

PM 4.0.4, Jboss 7.1.1

Answer (score 2):

The error you've got implies that you're trying to indicate a type parameter on a class that's not generic, that is, the class that doesn't expect it.

Examination of past Java EE releases showed that within Java EE 5 the [`ListDataModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/model/ListDataModel.html) is non-generic, while in Java EE 6+ [`ListDataModel<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/ListDataModel.html) indeed is.

As generics has become a Java artifact since Java SE 5 ages, Sun probably decided to leave a non-generic version of list model for Java EE 5.

As for the solution, look for old JSF libraries in your classpath and upgrade them to JSF 2+ (as of December 2013, the JSF version is 2.2). Alternatively, as application servers come bundled with JSF, and that you've got the most recent one, you can just as safely remove the webapp's JSF library altogether.